# Expected value for a binomial distribution

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose we take, as given, the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}=n 2^{n-1}.$$
Assuming only this result (or as little as possible), does the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}=np$$
follow obviously? Clearly, the second result can be obtained by differentiating $(p+x)^n$, or by considering the linearity of expected values. I'm more curious to know if the two identities can be seen to be equivalent in some some elementary fashion.

Comment: It follows immediately for $p=1/2$ (divide by $2^n$) but no other $p$.

Comment: I think one of the $p'$s should be a $1-p$.

Comment: It is $\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}p^k p^{n-k}=np^n\cdot 2^{n-1}$, because $p^k p^{n-k}=p^n$

Comment: I think the most elementary approach would use:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}np\binom{n-1}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k-1}=np(p+1-p)^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Yes, typo has been fixed!  Thanks @user281392.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you want to calculate moments of the binomial distribution, using the Stirling's number of the second kind would be the best approach, due the identity:
$$
x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \brace k}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x-j)
$$
And:
$$
j(j-1)\ldots(j-t+1)\binom{n}{j}=
j(j-1)\ldots(j-t+1)\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}=
$$
$$
=n(n-1)\ldots(n-t+1)\frac{(n-t)!}{(j-t)!(n-j)!}=n(n-1)\ldots(n-t+1)\binom{n-t}{j-t}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k^l\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^l{n \brace m}\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(k-j)\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^l{n \brace m}\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(n-j)\binom{n-m}{k-m}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=...
$$
(The rest is the same as in the comment)

Comment: Right. So the real answer is either a straight out "no", or "there are more elementary approaches anyhow, so why bother?" Your response is appreciated nonetheless!